# Is it possible to color correct individual video segments in VSE in a video without affecting the other segments?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, color

I have a 5 minute video consisting of multiple strips--some are mp4, some are PNG image sequences. I would like to color correct individual strips, independent of the others. Most of the video has superimposed green screen foregrounds, which are mainly what need color correcting. There is no artifact.
I have tried highlighting the strip I am trying to change, and placing the cursor over it, but any changes I make affect the adjacent strip. I am using  under the Eevee render engine.
I have blender 2.8.3, Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

In the *Video Sequence Editor* you can add *Modifiers* to each strip individually, such as *Color Balance*, *Hue Correct*, *Curves* etc.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Thanks.